# PHP MySQL carousel slider query displays no data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an Owl slider in my current project, in which up to three images from the database are to be displayed. I can also call up all the data I need without any problems, but if I want to display 2 or 3 pictures in the slider, only the first picture is displayed and the other pictures wont displayed without an error.

What is the problem?

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 10px;">
   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

      <?php 
         $operator_one_id = escape($_GET['operator_one']);

         $query = "SELECT * FROM strat WHERE player_one_operator_id = $operator_one_id";
         $select_operator_one_strat = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

         $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_operator_one_strat);

             $player_one_operator_id = $row['player_one_operator_id'];
             $player_one_image_top = $row['player_one_image_top'];
             $player_one_image_ground = $row['player_one_image_ground'];
             $player_one_image_base = $row['player_one_image_base'];

             echo "<div class='item'><img src='./assets/img/maps/strats/$player_one_image_top' alt='Operator One Top Strat'></div>";
             echo "<div class='item'><img src='./assets/img/maps/strats/$player_one_image_ground' alt='Operator One Ground Strat'></div>";
             echo "<div class='item'><img src='./assets/img/maps/strats/$player_one_image_base' alt='Operator Base Strat'></div>";

     ?>

   </div>
</div>
```

[![
Left picture 1, right picture 2][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VygIY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VygIY.png)

Comment: Seeing how your screenshot shows a “broken image” icon, you most likely must have created an image source URL there, that does not actually exist, and returns a 404.

Comment: you need to add all your codes into question ajax and php.

Comment: Why are you creating _three_ items in _one_ loop iteration? If all three of those images are supposed to create _one_ slide, then they need to be wrapped in _one single_ `item` div, not three.

Comment: @CBroe I've just looked at the docs https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html the default items is 3 so I guess that's why. Maybe he has not configured the slider at all at init

Comment: the slider should only ever display one image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how html is rendered. With the following options you can change almost every class the way you want.

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
     <div class="owl-stage-outer">
          <div class="owl-stage">
              <div class="owl-item">...</div>
              <div class="owl-item">...</div>
              <div class="owl-item">...</div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

While loop will display all images in database until you not limit query, so, you dont need to specify each image.

Your php codes in while loop should look like this :

```
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
      <div class="owl-stage-outer">
          <div class="owl-stage">      
       <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_operator_one_strat)){ ?>
            <div class="owl-item">
                <img src="path-to-image/<?php echo $row['image-name']; ?>" />
            </div>
       <?php }?>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Documentation : https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-classes.html

***But you are trying to display specific images so your codes should look like this without while loop :***

```
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
      <div class="owl-stage-outer">
          <div class="owl-stage">      
       <?php $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_operator_one_strat);?>
            <div class="owl-item">
                <img src="path-to-image/<?php echo $row['image-1']; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item">
                <img src="path-to-image/<?php echo $row['image-2']; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item">
                <img src="path-to-image/<?php echo $row['image-3']; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="owl-item">
                <img src="path-to-image/<?php echo $row['image-4']; ?>" />
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

[Marquee is another choice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)